# How can I add a row to my SQL results between each "category" change in the data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I use SQL Server 2019 to produce a long list of shipping options. This list is produced by a simple query on a table containing the list items, and displayed on a handheld terminal. Users find it cumbersome and time-consuming to navigate the list to find the correct option, and must do so several times per day.

What I want to do is add a category name with a few dashes to the list, which I then display on the hand-held terminal. This will appear as a "page break" of sorts, which will allow them to quickly visually scan down the list.

The challenge here is that the terminal software is very basic and cannot be modified. It can only do one thing, which is to execute the "GetList" stored procedure and read each row from that procedure in order, to create the list which it then displays to the user.

The output **must** be a single varchar column no more than 64 characters wide, so I'm quite limited in what I can do.

I can modify the data table and query used by the stored procedure, and I've already had some success adding CategoryRank and ColumnRank columns and using those to change the order in which the list gets displayed to make more sense to users.

So for example,

Current Query:

```
  SELECT ListItem 
    FROM SymbolScanner.dbo.ShippingTypes WITH(NOLOCK))
ORDER BY CategoryRank,
         ColumnRank
```

ShippingTypes table:

```
ListItem varchar(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
Category varchar(100) NOT NULL,
CategoryRank int NOT NULL,
ColumnRank int NOT NULL
```

Sample Data (the real list is hundreds of items long):

```
ListItem                    Category    CategoryRank  ColumnRank
RM 1st Class No Tracking    Royal Mail  1             1
RM 1st Class Tracked        Royal Mail  1             2
RM 2nd Class No Tracking    Royal Mail  1             3
RM 2nd Class Tracked        Royal Mail  1             4
TNT 24 Hour Tracked         TNT         2             1
TNT 24 Hour No Tracking     TNT         2             2
TNT 48 Hour Tracked         TNT         2             3
TNT 48 Hour no Tracking     TNT         2             4
DHL 24 Hour Tracked         DHL         3             1
DHL 48 Hour Tracked         DHL         3             1
```

Current Output:

```
RM 1st Class No Tracking
RM 1st Class Tracked
RM 2nd Class No Tracking
RM 2nd Class Tracked
TNT 24 Hour Tracked
TNT 24 Hour No Tracking
TNT 48 Hour Tracked
TNT 48 Hour No Tracking
DHL 24 Hour Tracked
DHL 48 Hour Tracked
```

The result is just a list of varchars, ordered in the way I want them ordered. Which is great, but I want to add a visual break between each category which includes the category name, to make it easier for users to quickly scroll down and see when the category changes.

Desired Output:

```
---- Royal Mail ----
RM 1st Class No Tracking
RM 1st Class Tracked
RM 2nd Class No Tracking
RM 2nd Class Tracked
---- TNT ----
TNT 24 Hour Tracked
TNT 24 Hour No Tracking
TNT 48 Hour Tracked
TNT 48 Hour No Tracking
---- DHL ----
DHL 24 Hour Tracked
DHL 48 Hour Tracked
```

So what I need is an extra row inserted into my results, which includes the category name and a few dash characters, before each change of category. I'm certain there's some SQL gymnastics that can be pulled off to do this, I'm just a bit lost at where to even start.

Comment: Why don't use input this query into Temp tables inside a stored procedure? Each table could be a shipping company and have a final table to insert all your line breaks and return the result set.

Comment: Could do, but I think mweber's solution of simply using the existing columnrank value and category name already in the table, and using a subquery on a UNION-ed set of headers is very simple, efficient and elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your header lines in a second query and merge the results by UNIONing:

```
SELECT ListItem FROM
(

SELECT ListItem, CategoryRank, ColumnRank
FROM ShippingTypes

UNION ALL

SELECT '---- ' + Category + ' ----', CategoryRank, 0
FROM ShippingTypes
GROUP BY Category, CategoryRank
) sub

ORDER BY CategoryRank,
     ColumnRank
```

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/66685/4)

Answer (score 1):

Can this work for you?

```
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(listitem,category,categoryrank,columnrank) AS (
          SELECT 'RM 1st Class No Tracking','Royal Mail',1,1
UNION ALL SELECT 'RM 1st Class Tracked','Royal Mail',1,2
UNION ALL SELECT 'RM 2nd Class No Tracking','Royal Mail',1,3
UNION ALL SELECT 'RM 2nd Class Tracked','Royal Mail',1,4
UNION ALL SELECT 'TNT 24 Hour Tracked','TNT',2,1
UNION ALL SELECT 'TNT 24 Hour No Tracking','TNT',2,2
UNION ALL SELECT 'TNT 48 Hour Tracked','TNT',2,3
UNION ALL SELECT 'TNT 48 Hour no Tracking','TNT',2,4
UNION ALL SELECT 'DHL 24 Hour Tracked','DHL',3,1
UNION ALL SELECT 'DHL 48 Hour Tracked','DHL',3,1
)
-- end of your input. Real query starts here,
-- and replace the comma below with "WITH"
,
the_union(category,listitem) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    category
  , '------ '||category||'  -----'
  FROM indata
  UNION ALL SELECT
    category
  , listitem
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  listitem
FROM the_union
ORDER BY 
  category
, listitem
;
-- out          listitem         
-- out --------------------------
-- out  ------ DHL  -----
-- out  DHL 24 Hour Tracked
-- out  DHL 48 Hour Tracked
-- out  ------ Royal Mail  -----
-- out  RM 1st Class No Tracking
-- out  RM 1st Class Tracked
-- out  RM 2nd Class No Tracking
-- out  RM 2nd Class Tracked
-- out  ------ TNT  -----
-- out  TNT 24 Hour No Tracking
-- out  TNT 24 Hour Tracked
-- out  TNT 48 Hour Tracked
-- out  TNT 48 Hour no Tracking
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL databases are designed to manipulate data, not format it. Usually, this would be dealt with by the middleware that queries the data and prepares the result for viewing, but you don't seem to have any.

Comment: But the point is spot-on. You desire "formatted" output and tsql is not suited for such purposes. Here you had a single column of actual data which makes this approach "doable". Add additional columns and this approach quickly falls apart.

Comment: Incorrect, check the accepted answer for a solution which works for any number of columns. SQL Server has been used for formatting since it came out, and is fully supported by Microsoft for such tasks since SQL Server 2017 which introduced the FORMAT() function.